# Событие Тапа по элементу Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, события, windows-phone-8.1

Есть элемент, по клику на который должна происходить смена его фона, но никак не получается правильно задать для этого параметр для `RoutedEvent` в `XAML`. Мой код:

```
<Border Tapped="Border_Tapped"
        Height="50"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        CornerRadius="5"
        BorderBrush="#9e9e9e"
        BorderThickness="0 0 0 3">
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="Background" Color="#ff567cd3"/>
        </Border.Background>
        <Border.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Tapped">   <!-- Вот тут ошибка -->
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background"
                                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                      Duration="0:0:.3"
                                                      EnableDependentAnimation="True">
                            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#ff9e9e9e" KeyTime="0:0:0.15"/>
                            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#ff567cd3" KeyTime="0:0:0.3"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Border.Triggers>

        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="20"
                   FontWeight="SemiBold"
                   Foreground="#fff"
                   Text="Нажми меня"/>
</Border>
```

Текст ошибки:

> Событие "Tapped" отлично от RoutedEvent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Казалось бы тривиальная задача и ошибка в чем-то меньшем, но попросту поддерживается только `Loaded` и все. Все связано из-за смены с `Silverlight`. 
Провернуть это дело можно с помощью `Behaviors SDK (XAML)`

Добавляем бибилиотеку References -> Add Reference ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляем ссылки на пространство имен:

```
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"
```

Ваш код немного переписываем

```
<Border Height="50"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        CornerRadius="5"
        x:Name="MyBorder"
        BorderBrush="#9e9e9e"
        Background="#ff567cd3"
        BorderThickness="0 0 0 3">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
            <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource ColorStoryboard}"/>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="20"
            FontWeight="SemiBold"
            Foreground="#fff"
            Text="Нажми меня"/>
</Border>
```

Добавил x:Name к `Border` для которого будем анимировать `Background`. Саму анимацию расположим не внутри `media:ControlStoryboardAction`, это связано с тем, что `Behavior` находится не в дереве элементов, отсюда не имеет доступ к `Border` по `x:Name`:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="ColorStoryboard">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder"
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                      Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                      EnableDependentAnimation="True">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#ff9e9e9e"
                                 KeyTime="0:0:0.15"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#ff567cd3"
                                 KeyTime="0:0:0.3"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

Если нужно изменить ещё что-то, то стоит заметить, что при объявление элементов внутри 'Storyboard' они добавляется в колелкцию `TimelineCollection`. Добавим  `x:Name="MyTextBlock"` к нашему `TextBlock` и обновим анимацию:

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="ColorStoryboard">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder"
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                      Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                      EnableDependentAnimation="True">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#ff9e9e9e"
                                 KeyTime="0:0:0.15"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#ff567cd3"
                                 KeyTime="0:0:0.3"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyTextBlock"
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                    Value="Спасибо"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Comment: Спасибо, выглядит весьма неплохо. Правда я уже успел переделать Border в Button и освоить ControlTemplate для разных состояний. Не успел правда отписаться, так как доделываю еще.

Comment: Использовал Вашу подсказку в другом месте, но не могу понять, как можно параллельно анимации изменить свойство другого элемента. Конкретно к этому примеру, допустим мы по тапу на бордер анимируем его цвет, и у текстбокса(не анимация) меняем Текст, или его Visibility.

Comment: обновил ответ дополнением

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Comment: А можно еще небольшой вопрос? Заметил разницу между `Tapped="SomeEvent_Handler"` и `Behavior` на элементе `Grid`. Событие распространялось на Тап по дочерним элементам, а `Behavior` почему-то не всегда отрабатывает при Тапе на областях, занятых дочерними элементами. Можно как-то растиражировать `Behavior` на дочерние элементы без копипаста всего бехавиора?

Comment: Прошу прощения, все нормально работает, недоразобрался.